# java websocket server: can I recognize clients?

Tags: java, websocket

I was wondering if it was possible to distinguish the clients connected to a websocket server. In my project I have to be able to send messages from multiple clients and send them to a specific client. So my question is: is there a way to be able to recognize between different clients?
I try to use getId() method in the Session Interface but it is useless for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

When you register a new web_socket client, you can send the client information, for example the user_mail or simply a guid for example:

**HTML PAGE**

```
var pagesessionid = generateGuid();
ws.connect('ws://' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + 'ws?myclientparam=' + pagesessionid);
or

ws.connect('ws://' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + 'ws?myclientparam=' + userid);
```

**Servlet code**:

```
    public class BrowserWebSocket extends WebSocketServlet {
...
...
..
    @Override
    protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String string, HttpServletRequest hsr) {

        String myclientvalue= "";


        if (hsr.getParameter("myclientparam") != null) {
            myclientvalue= hsr.getParameter("myclientparam");

ClientWebSocket webSocket = new ClientWebSocket(myclientvalue);
```

The web socket client class:

```
public class ClientWebSocket extends MessageInbound implements Serializable {
    public WsOutbound outbound;
    public String _myclient= "";
    public ClientWebSocket(String myclient) {
        _myclient= myclient;
    }
```

The you can use `myclient` to  the clients.

Here I have used standard  servlet with tomcat websocket, but it is the same also for other situations

I hope it helps